# Linq to XML read method throws NullReferenceException using C# in VS2017

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my XML structure:

```
<root>
    <report>
        <results>
            <result>
                <name> name 1 </name>
            </result>
            <result>
                <name> name 2 </name>
            </result>
       </results>
    </report>
</root>
```

I want to read the information within *result* and create an object to set it's attribute to the value. This is my code to do this:

**Read from XML:**

```
XDocument rootDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath)
var vul = from r in rootDocument.Descendants("result")
select new
{
    Name = r.Element("name").Value
};
```

**Create new object:**

```
foreach(var r in vul)
{
    Object a = new Object()
    {
        Name = r.Name
    };
}
```

The Problem is that this produces a NullReferenceException when calling

```
rootDocument.Descendants("result")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried your code with your xml, it works fine for me.

Comment: did you check the filepath, Is it possible that rootDocuments returns null?

Comment: Checked that already, the rootDocument returns what it should. @hsnbl

Comment: This code works fine for me to - have you reduced this code from a large code base? Did you have other properties that were getting set in the select?

Comment: I reduce the posted XML-file because it is much bigger. @Scrobi

Comment: Use following : Name = (string)r.Element("name")

Comment: No Change @jdweng

Comment: I debugged the part where the exception is thrown. The value of *vul* is
 *{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<System.Xml.Linq.XElemnt, <>f__AnonymousType0<string>>}* but at *Current* the value is null.

Comment: Add ToList() : (from r in rootDocument.Descendants("result")
select new
{
    Name = (string)r.Element("name")
}).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this Error. I don't know why but calling the value of an element causes it. I changed

```
Name = r.Element("name").Value
```

to

```
Name= r.Element("name")
```

Comment: It will still be null in the case that caused the previous failure. You're just avoiding the exception by not attempting to access a property on a null reference.

Comment: That's right. Proper exception handling will do the work too.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your select is trying to access an element that does not exist.

For example there is a missing `name` element from your original xml:

e.g. This xml will fail

```
<root>
    <report>
        <results>
            <result>
                <name> name 1 </name>
            </result>
            <result>
                <name> name 2 </name>
            </result>
            <result>
                <surname> name 2 </surname> //will fail when loop gets here
            </result>
       </results>
    </report>
</root>
```

If it is possible that name element will not always exist you can update the code to handle null

```
var vul = from r in rootDocument.Descendants("result")
    select new
    {
        Name = r.Element("name")?.Value, //this will return null
    };
```

..as `r.Name` can be null you need to account for this in the for loop.

```
foreach (var r in vul)
{
    string Name = r.Name ?? string.empty; 
}
```

Comment: I checked it. The code stops working with the first <name> which is definetly there.

Comment: You may need to add your original xml file and code, as there is no issue with the code and xml you have added.

Comment: I can not upload any original content. But knowing that my Code works helps a lot. I need to work thorugh the xml and search for any errors. Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas: Note that if your elements are implicitly in a namespace, then you'll need to specify that in the `Element` call too. That may well be the problem. Note that you don't have to show your *real* original content, but you should include a *representative* example.